# face detection does not work

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

I'm using OpenCV on a 64-bit Win 7, with VS2010 (C++).

I've tried so many source codes for detecting faces, they compile and run, but no detection takes place.

I'll give two examples:
1) In this first example, I'm using source code from:

http://www.bsd-noobz.com/opencv-guide/60-3-face-detection

I get the picture, but not the squares.

2) In this second example, I'm using code that I had downloaded some time ago (can't remember where from). This one shows the stream from the webcam, and again no detection is happening.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

 /** Function Headers */
 void detectAndDisplay2( Mat frame );

 /** Global variables */
 String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
 String eyes_cascade_name = "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
 CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
 CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;

//RNG rng(12345);

 /** @function main */
 int main()
 {
   CvCapture* capture;
   Mat frame;

   //-- 1. Load the cascades
   if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading face cascade\n"); return -1; };
   if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading eye cascade\n"); return -1; };

   //-- 2. Read the video stream
   capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 1 );
   if( capture )
   {
     while( true )
     {
   frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

   //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame
       if( !frame.empty() )
       { detectAndDisplay2( frame ); }
       else
       { printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!"); break; }

       int c = waitKey(10);
       if( (char)c == 'c' ) { break; }
      }
   }
   cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
   cvDestroyWindow("Capture - Face detection");

   return 0;
 }

/** @function detectAndDisplay */
void detectAndDisplay2( Mat frame )
{
  vector<Rect> faces;
  Mat frame_gray;

  cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
  equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

  //-- Detect faces
  face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

  for( int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
  {
    Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
    ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );

    Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
    vector<Rect> eyes;

    //-- In each face, detect eyes
    eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

    for( int j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++ )
     {
       Point center( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5 );
       int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25 );
       circle( frame, center, radius, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );
     }
  }
  //-- Show what you got
  imshow( "Processed", frame_gray );
  imshow( "Capture - Face detection", frame );

 }
```

I'd be really grateful if someone can help.

Comment: Make sure you have `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml` in the same folder like your program. For me, this codes works.

Comment: Thanks. The problem seems to have been with the Property Sheets. I opened a new project using new (correctly organized) property sheets that used the standard OpenCV libraries (rather than recompiling for 64-bit) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `opencv` project in [github](https://github.com/trishume/eyeLike). This error stems from two issues that I can see.

1) Make sure you’ve installed the correct OpenCV version. I suggest this [install guide](http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/)… It worked well for me.

2) Then, make sure you have added `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml` to inside of the executable file – which should be in a folder like `../build/bin/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml` when you built the project).